# Detect if e-mail has been read by the recipient?

Tags: email

How do I know if the e-mail I sent someone has been read already by him / her. If I heard it correctly, it's called a **read receipt**. How do I use or implement something like that?

Comment: What is your platform you are sending emails from?

Comment: Post your Operating System and Email client or type of Webmail you are using, edit your original post to include this information.

Comment: You can't, reliably. Email clients (and their users) can skip sending a receipt, or don't support this feature at all.

Comment: What Daniel Beck said is true.

Comment: Daniel is correct, BUT depending on your environment, your mail administrator can most likely run a trace.

Comment: What @Daniel Beck said.  I always refuse to send read receipts, and I judge you every time I see you requested one. ;)

Comment: Related (if not a dupe): [How to prove that an email has been sent?](http://superuser.com/questions/77131/how-to-prove-that-an-email-has-been-sent)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to absolutely know for sure.  Some environments support it within a given enterprise (ie, if you're emailing a co-worker).  But if you're mailing someone else at random on the net, you can't.

There are some tricks to **attempt** to get around this.  Many "advertising newsletter" types things from stores send mail only in HTML and contain embedded images that point to a unique URL on their server that is mapped to you.  However, even this won't give you assurance that they read it since many mail readers are configured not to load images by default, for example.

Now, lets say you **could** actually detect through some trickery they opened it.  Could you tell they read it?  Could you tell that they clicked quickly, realized they clicked on the wrong one and clicked on another one within a second?  You can't.

The best thing to do is put a phrase in it that says "the magic word is *dune-buggy*" and then call them and ask if they know what the magic word is :-)

Comment: Such image is called [a web bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_bug).

Comment: Also known as "PattyMail" after HP tried to use these to figure out who on their board was leaking information to the press.

Comment: Just as read as terms and conditions you explicitly confirm to have read.

Answer (score 0):

On Outlook 2007 it is under options:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

there is no way for this. For the emails you are interested in, I suggest you to send them as normal mails, then add a mark to them, and review after some days if they have been answered, case notm send them again. For me it works